# Using a current row value into a subquery

Tags: sql

I am trying to count how many times an order_Id appears in a subquery and then present it right next to the Average Value of each customer orders. Here is what I have tried.

```
select person ,AVG(orderTotal) as avgOrdersValue , timesSeen 
from 
    (
select  
Customer_Id as person 
,Order_Id
, SUM(total)as orderTotal 
,(select COUNT(Order_Id) as timesSeen  
from Orders where  Customer_Id=person  group by Order_Id
    )
from Orders group by Customer_Id  Order_Id order by person ) tablealias 
group by person
```

And here is the message i get: "*Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'person'.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
No column name was specified for column 4 of 'gg'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'timesSeen'.*"

Comment: You need to put your subquery after 'from'

Comment: Can you explain your schema and what your ultimate goal is?  Perhaps make a sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your description, this may be the query that you want:

```
select person, AVG(OrderTotal), COUNT(distinct orderId)
from (select Customer_id as person, Order_id, SUM(total) as OrderTotal
      from Orders
      group by Customer_Id, Order_Id
     ) o
group by person
```

I say "may" because I would expect `OrderId` to be a unique key in the `Orders` table.  So, the inner subquery wouldn't be doing anything.  Perhaps you mean something like `OrderLines` in the inner query.

The reason your query fails is because of the correlation statement:

```
where Customer_Id = person
```

You intend for this to use the value from the outer query ("person") to relate to the inner one ("Customer_Id").  However, the inner query does not know the alias in the `select` clause of the outer one.  So, "Person" is undefined.  When doing correlated subqueries, you should *always* use table aliases.  That query should look more like:

```
(select COUNT(o2.Order_Id) as timesSeen  
 from Orders o2 where  o2.Customer_Id=o.person 
 group by o2.Order_Id
)
```

Assuming "o" is the alias for orders in the outer query.  Correlated subqueries are not needed.  You should just simplify the query.

Comment: @jayt.dev . . . Not a good naming convention, but the first query should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the name of your result column in a subquery. Name your subquery `Orders` table `o` and do `WHERE Customer_id = o.Customer_Id`. Preferably make up aliases for each of these tables so that they do not get mixed up.

Comment: How do I name subquery Orders "o" ?